# Video Editor Change Resolution Still Crops Instead of Resize (3.1/3.2)

Tags: compositing-nodes, resolution

Changing the resolution crops the video instead of resize it. Im adding the image sequence via compositing node editor, there are no options to specify fitting or stretching. Sometimes i need to test a certain effect that's why i want to reduce the percentage so i can quickly render out an mp4 to view it because it's too slow to view in blender especially if you use alot of nodes in the compositor.

[image]

I found these threads they had the same problem [Video editor crops instead of resize when changing resolution (2.93/2.92)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227788/video-editor-crops-instead-of-resize-when-changing-resolution-2-93-2-92) and https://blenderartists.org/t/video-editing-changing-resolution-does-not-work-anymore/1308464 but no response. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the size of imported movie clips in the *Compositor*, you can add the *Distort* > *Scale* node. There you can choose between scaling *Absolute*, *Relative*, to *Scene Size* or *Render Size* and for the latter you can switch options to either *Stretch*, *Fit* or *Crop* the movie clip to the actual render size:

[image: scaling movie clip]

Comment: cool thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**//EDIT:** This answer was for resizing video strips in the *Video Sequence Editor* before the question was rephrased. Maybe this helps other people with similar problems.

The problem is that in the past there were complaints that, when importing videos and images from different sources and different aspect ratios, they got stretched to fit the render dimensions, although this might not always be desirable when you have varying source dimensions on purpose.

So the behavior was changed to not alter the original source dimensions when imported by default. However, you can change this either on import when you're adding a strip or later when it's already imported.

To change it directly on import, change the setting in the *Add Movie Strip* dialog box with the *Fit Method* option. The default is *Use Original Size*, but you can also choose to either stretch or scale to fit or fill (the option you choose will be remembered by Blender for the next import):

[image: fit method]

If you want to resize an already imported strip later on in the *Video Sequencer* you can change it in the *Sequencer* or *Preview* menu under *Image* > *Apply* (you can also select multiple video or image strips by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>):

[image: image apply scale]

Comment: hi thank you for your time and help. sorry i forgot to specify how im importing the images. I updated my post with this: Im adding an image sequence via compositing node editor, there are no options to specify fitting or stretching. Sometimes i need to test a certain effect that's why i want to reduce the percentage so i can quickly render out an mp4 file for viewing because it's too slow to view especially if there are alot of nodes in compositor.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie If you are not using the _VSE_, maybe you shouldn't use the #video-sequence-editor tag but #compositing-nodes instead and not link to questions that are dealing with the _VSE_. Or are you going to use the compositing result in the _Video Sequence Editor_ afterwards?

Comment: oops you are right sorry my bad i used the wrong tag. i changed it to compositing-nodes. so probably it's not possible?